# How to add reference `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.dll` in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, reference

I'm writing a customized activity for TFS build process workflow, e.g. guideline [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-your-own-activity.aspx).

The post requires to add reference to `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.dll` at path `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a`. I cannot find this path on my machine installing Visual Studio 2012.

Where would I find this reference?

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio are you using? Express, Pro, Ultimate?

Comment: My VS 2012 is Ultimate

Comment: I'm using 2013 and that library isn't present. It looks like it only existed for 2010 and 2012 according to TechNet articles. But the documentation does say it should be in the GAC. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146(v=vs.110).aspx in the very bottom section. I know that doesn't help you solve the reference issue, but it at least assures you that you're not nuts.

Comment: Where can I download this file, it's not on my machine.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread, but in case anyone else runs into this, just download the stand alone TFS Object Model installer.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer states, it's shipped with VS 2010 so you'll need to install that and then you should be able to find it.

For any of you trying to do this with VS 2013 / TFS 2013 you need Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client version=12.0.0.0

This file is located in the folder

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Answer (score 1):

Version 10.0 of the file is shipped with Team Explorer or Visual Studio **2010**.
It is copied directly to the GAC but you can extract it using the command line `COPY` command.

Install VS 2010 on your machine, open a command prompt and navigate to `C:\Windows\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client\{Version}\`

Then `COPY` Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.dll to a folder of your choice.

Finally, my advice would be that you use the version included in VS 2012, that would make things much easier. The method described above also works for Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.dll 11.0 (aka VS 2012 version).

Comment: The above is slightly wrong.  Here is the full command: `copy c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client
\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a .` The example above is missing the **assembly** part of the path